# Альтернатива использования объекта в качестве параметра

Tags: java, android

С вопросом о передаче объекта в качестве параметра по значению вроде бы все понятно - в примере ниже код в методе `actionTimer` не повлияет на объект timer[0].

Но появляется вопрос, как все же можно решить такую задачу - одинаково работать с однотипными объектами, используя один и тот же метод? Т.е. какие рабочие альтернативы можно использовать для реализации задачи, решаемой в коде ниже?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private Timer []timer = new Timer[10];

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainactivity);

        actionTimer (timer[0]);
    }

    private void actionTimer (Timer localTimer) {
        localTimer = null;
        localTimer = new Timer();
    }
}
```

Или решение только одно - для каждого объекта использовать свой метод, например как в коде ниже?

```
actionTimer1 ();
    }

    private void actionTimer1 () {
        timer[0] = null;
        timer[0] = new Timer();
    }
```

Comment: Непонятно что вы пытаетесь достичь. Если вы хотите чтоб метод `actionTimer` поменял `timer[0]` то передайте 2 входящий параметра - массив `timer` и `int` индекс 0.

Comment: @anber Спасибо, ваш способ сработал!

Answer (score 1):

вызов функции

```
actionTimer (0);
```

функция

```
private void actionTimer (int index) {
        if (index < 10 && index > 0)
            timer[index] = new Timer();
        else // опционально, но полезно 
            throw new IndexOutOfBoundsException(outOfBoundsMsg(index));


    }
```